# Django How to refactor duplicate method

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 2.2 and in my view I have two functions that do the same thing but only one element changes. I would like to try to improve my code so that I don't repeat the same thing more times, basically do what the `vm_schedule_power_on_vm` function does and
`vm_schedule_power_off_vm` into one function. The only thing that will change is the call of `vmware_poweron` in the `vm_schedule_power_on_vm` function and `vmware_poweroff`  in the `vm_schedule_power_off_vm` function.

```
path('vm/schedule/<int:pk>/powered_on/', vm.vm_schedule_power_on_vm,
    name='vm_schedule_power_on_vm'),
path('vm/schedule/<int:pk>/powered_off/', vm.vm_schedule_power_off_vm,
    name='vm_schedule_power_off_vm')


def vm_schedule_power_on_vm(request, pk):
    sch = VmSchedule.objects.get(pk=pk)
    mylistvm, mylist = list(), list()
    mydate = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    for i in sch.vms.all():
        if i.lock:
            return 'locked'
        # here the order has importance because 
        # I try to have the start time and at the end the end time. 
        mylist.append(mydate)
        mylist.append(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        mylist.append(i.name)
        mylist.append(i.vmware.hostname)
        # only this line changes each time
        mylist.append(vmware_poweron(i))
        mylist.append(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        mylist.append(sch.schedule)
        mylistvm.append(mylist)
        mylist = list()
    vm_logs_export(mylistvm)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(mylistvm))


def vm_schedule_power_off_vm(request, pk):
    sch = VmSchedule.objects.get(pk=pk)
    mylistvm, mylist = list(), list()
    mydate = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    for i in sch.vms.all():
        if i.lock:
            return 'locked'
        mylist.append(mydate)
        mylist.append(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        mylist.append(i.name)
        mylist.append(i.vmware.hostname)
        # only this line changes each time
        mylist.append(vmware_poweroff(i))
        mylist.append(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        mylist.append(sch.schedule)
        mylistvm.append(mylist)
        mylist = list()
    vm_logs_export(mylistvm)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(mylistvm))

# Example result of vm_schedule_power_on_vm or vm_schedule_power_off_vm
['09/12/2021', '13:54:33', 'API1VTEST11', 'ste1vvcsa', '13:54:33', 'testPowredOn02', 
 '09/12/2021', '13:54:33', 'API1VTEST12', 'ste1vvcsa', '13:54:33', 'testPowredOn02', 
 '09/12/2021', '13:54:33', 'API1VTEST2', 'ste1vvcsa', '13:54:33', 'testPowredOn02']


def vmware_poweron(vm):
    #return list of something
    
    
def vmware_poweroff(vm):
    #return list of something
    
# Example result of vmware_poweron or vmware_poweroff
[["09/12/2021", "13:54:33", "API1VTEST11", "ste1vvcsa", "13:54:33", "testPowredOn02", 
 "09/12/2021", "13:54:33", "API1VTEST12", "ste1vvcsa", "13:54:33", "testPowredOn02", 
 "09/12/2021", "13:54:33", "API1VTEST2", "ste1vvcsa", "13:54:33", "testPowredOn02"]
```

I thought of doing in one fonction like this [past code here](https://dpaste.org/2fGb#L1,9,20,21,22,23)

Comment: Why not using one fonction with a third paramater "on"/"off", than you just use a if on the code that have a different behavior ?

Comment: @Tbaki yes I did look [in one function](https://dpaste.org/2fGb#L1,9,20,21,22,23)

Comment: @Tbaki the only problem is the if condition is in a loop.

Comment: @panda42 You need to use the `continue` in the `if` condition instead of `return` a value. That will break the loop, seems like you need to skip instead of returning.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to extract the shared operations into a more generically named function, e.g. `vm_schedule_power_operation`. Give this a third parameter, `operation`, and pass either `vmware_poweron` or `vmware_poweroff` as that parameter.

When you reach the line that changes in the function, modify that line to call `operation(i)` instead of `vmware_poweron` or `vmware_poweroff` directly.

Then, your `on`/`off` functions can look like this:

```py
def vm_schedule_power_on_vm(request, pk):
    vm_schedule_power_operation(request, pk, vmware_poweron)

def vm_schedule_power_off_vm(request, pk):
    vm_schedule_power_operation(request, pk, vmware_poweroff)
```

Comment: Yeah I thought some think like that but when your in a view it's need to return something a render or else.

Comment: Well, add `return` to the call :)